# The sum of the integration of g and $g^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $g$ be a strictly increasing continuous function mapping $[a,b]$ onto 
$[A,B]$, and, as usual, let $g^{-1}: [A,B] \to [a,b]$ denote its inverse function. 
Use geometric insight to visualize the equation $\int_a^b g + \int_A^B g^{-1} = bB - aA$.

Apply this to the function $g(\theta) = \tan \theta$ on the interval $[0,b]$ for a fixed $b \in (0,\pi/2)$.

Can someone give me some help on how to set this up?

Comment: **Hint:** Draw it schematically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw the graph of $g$ on the $x,y$-coordinate system, it contains exactly the $(x,g(x))$ points, $x\in [a,b]$. But these are the same as the $(g^{-1}(y),y)$ points, for $y\in [A,B]$.

So that, $\int_A^Bg^{-1}=\int_A^Bg^{-1}(y)\,dy$ appears on the picture *horizontally*, as the area from the $y$-axis to the graph of $g$.

Subtracting the two rectangles, $(\int_a^bg\,-(b-a)A)\ +\ (\int_A^Bg^{-1}\,-(B-A)a )$ we get the area of the rectangle $[a,b]\times [A,B]$.

Comment: Thats not what i came up with with your hint, O.o  going to see if ca figure this part out before attempting the second part. thx.

Comment: I'd want to draw it for you.