# Still having trouble following a surface area function?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g$ be a strictly increasing continuous function mapping $[a,b]$ onto 
$[A,B]$, and, as usual, let $g^{-1}: [A,B] \to [a,b]$ denote its inverse function.

Consider the equation $\int_a^b g + \int_A^B g^{-1} = bB - aA$.

Apply it to the function $g(\theta) = \tan \theta$ on the interval $[0,b]$ for a fixed $b \in (0,\pi/2)$.

I think it looks like.

$\int_0^b \tan \theta + \int_0^{ \tan b} \arctan \theta = b (\tan b)- 0$ where $b \in (0,\pi/2)$.

Is this what i am being asked to do? any hints/ help much appreciated.

Comment: If I had to guess, I think you are trying to find the antiderivative of $\arctan \theta$ (or $\tan\theta$; whichever one you don't "know" yet). Is this really the way the problem was stated?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396816/the-sum-of-the-integration-of-g-and-g-1?rq=1 This is exactly how it was stated, and i do understand what is listed there (spent some time drawing pictures) but i can't follow what is being asked of me since the value of b is floating in that interval.

It just seems so wierd/odd to me to ask/state a question that i know i am misunderstanding the question in part or full

Comment: When I read the question (specifically the wording "consider the equation") I get the impression that the equation has already been justified (that one admits a great proof without words), but it is now being used to derive something else you didn't know.

Comment: I think the idea is to start from the equation you've written down, and derive $\int_0^x\arctan\theta\,d\theta$ from your previous knowledge of $\int_0^b\tan\theta\,d\theta$.

Comment: it was asked to be proved but thats not the part that i don't understand which is why i changed the wording myself.  do you think im supposed to compute both of those integrals to show that equals the formula given? ( we haven't talked about anti derivatives in this class)

Comment: If you've changed the words, could you please put the exact wording of the original problem in a blockquote? The wording here is throwing me for a loop, and it may help to be able to see the original.

Comment: antiderivative = indefinite integral (at least, for intro calc students)

Comment: Sorry to post again, so you mean write $\int_0^{ \tan b} \arctan \theta = b (\tan b)- 0 - \int_0^b \tan \theta$ and then compute the integral of $\tan \theta$ over those bounds n leave it like that?

Comment: @Mario Carneiro this is the original wording ----> http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396816/the-sum-of-the-integration-of-g-and-g-1?rq=1

Comment: yes, and then substitute $x=\tan b$ so that you can get a result of the form $\int\arctan x=[\cdots]+c$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro you just made some things make alot of sense in my textbook! ( not sure if its related to this question though, =0 )

Comment: Glad to help ;)